# slurm gpu srun status PD

Tags: gpu, nvidia, slurm

am a nube to slurm , my first cluster concludes 3 servers with one slurmgpu .
guilt this simple app that runs on gpu , and localy it is running well .
while trying to run it with srun i am not getting any errors just PD state in squeue.

this is my sbtach run file looks like this :

```
!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=test_gpu
#SBATCH --output=res_gpu.txt
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:2
#SBATCH --partition=debug
#SBATCH --nodelist=slurmgpu
#SBATCH --time=00:00:10

export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-12.1/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-12.1/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

srun ./add.v3
```

this is my /etc/slurm-llnl/gres.conf

```
NodeName=slurmgpu Name=gpu File=/dev/nvidia0
NodeName=slurmgpu Name=gpu File=/dev/nvidia1
```

no MPI used , just cuda

any one can help ?

tried running localy on slurm gpu and success,
tried putting the gres.conf under slurm01 which is the master node.